# TFS (Service) Drop Location for Build not accessible

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am using TFS (**Service** not Server) for my source control needs. I am trying to create new build definition using network share (\\pc\share with full permissions) as my **drop location**, however it looks like whatever I do i am getting **bad user name/password error**. does TFS supports Network Share feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the hosted build controller, you cannot use a UNC path for drop folder. However, if you set up your own build controller accessing the Tfs Service to do your build, you can specify a UNC folder identifiable by the build server. Use a Source Control folder instead.

Comment: if I use a Source Control Folder then I have to download the builds manually? so I can test them using IIS web server. is it really hard to roll my own build controller?

Comment: It's not hard at all. I have set up it up all the time. You would need Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 installation media, just install the build services. Make sure you run your build service with a user that has access on the team project collection. Set up your controller to use the team project collection.

Comment: ahh ic. Do I need to install TFS on the development machine, or it could be installed on any machine? Also does the Express version of TFS offers this feature?

Comment: Just the build service of Tfs. Usually the build machine is separate from development machine, something with a well documentation configuration of dev tools, so you can manage the version of visual studio, updates, etc. that you are building against. 

You could use your development machine as well. The TFS service will run builds in background, which could affect the performance of your machine.

Comment: Just the build service of Tfs. Usually the build machine is separate from development machine, something with a well documentation configuration of dev tools, so you can manage the version of visual studio, updates, etc. that you are building against. 

You could use your development machine as well. The TFS service will run builds in background, which could affect the performance of your machine.